# One XSD for both whole document and fragment?

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, xml-validation

I wish to create a grammar able to validate both a full XML document and a fragment of it.

I have a set of documents aggregate in a “batch”. Each document has a set of meta-data:

```
<batch>
    <document>
        <metadata1 />
        <metadata2 />
        <metadata3 />
    </document>
    <document>
        <metadata1 />
        <metadata2 />
        <metadata3 />
    </document>
</batch>
```

My SpringBatch process splits the batch in documents (with [StaxEventItemReader](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/xml/StaxEventItemReader.html))
I wish to validate a sub XML representing a single document:

```
<document>
    <metadata1 />
    <metadata2 />
    <metadata3 />
</document>
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250005/can-i-validade-a-xml-file-against-xsd-fragment-in-java) that I can’t use partial XSD to validate XML.

However, **is there is a way, *while avoiding duplication*, to validate with two XSDs, where one would validate the fragment, and the other would validate the batch?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal with a single XSD by specifying multiple possible root elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="batch">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="document" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="document">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="metadata1" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="metadata2" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="metadata3" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

This way documents may have either a `batch` or a `document` root element, and there is no definition duplication.

Comment: Crystal clear, work perfectly. Thank you! 
In addition, it's allow me to understand better [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614015/working-with-multiple-xsds)